# What is blackice-icecap user console on port 8081 on my MacBook air?

Tags: network, fink

I have Fink installed on my MacBook Air and when I looked for open ports I see the following which I am unfamiliar with:

8080 common http-proxy/second web server port.

8081 blackice-icecap ICECap user console.

What are these and should I be concerned with them?

Answer (score 3):

The "blackice-icecap user console" is a piece of administration software for a firewall system. However, it is very unlikely that you have that system running on your MacBook Air.

In essence your port list just writes the name of the software that has registered the port with IANA - i.e. they're saying that "our software uses this port". However, other software can also use the port number - and this is what happened for you.

You can run the following commands in the Terminal to find out, which program has opened the ports:

```
lsof -n -i4TCP:8080
lsof -n -i4TCP:8081
```

You'll find both the command name and the process ID (PID) of the program that opened the ports.

Whether or not you should be concerned about it depends on what that program is. If it is something you installed yourself, is aware of, and you're using - then that's OK. If it is something that is running without your knowledge, or you're no longer using, you will probably want to look further into it.

Comment: This is what came up with those prompts:

Comment: Did you forget to include something?

Comment: % lsof -n -ipTCP:8081
lsof: unknown protocol name (pTCP) in: -i pTCP:8081
lsof 4.91
 latest revision: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/
 latest FAQ: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/FAQ
 latest man page: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/lsof_man
 usage: [-?abhlnNoOPRtUvVX] [+|-c c] [+|-d s] [+D D] [+|-f[cgG]]
 [-F [f]] [-g [s]] [-i [i]] [+|-L [l]] [+|-M] [-o [o]] [-p s]
 [+|-r [t]] [-s [p:s]] [-S [t]] [-T [t]] [-u s] [+|-w] [-x [fl]] [--] [names]
Use the ``-h'' option to get more help information.

Comment: I just don't know what this is and how to get rid of it if it shouldn't be there.

Comment: You had a typo when you entered the command - you wrote "p" instead of "4". I suggest using cut-n-paste to ensure it is the correct command.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else comes across this information.  On my home network.  Those two ports and processes are used by a Dlink camera DCS-8000LH.   Try using the Fing App to scan your network.  It should identify the Manufacturer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/331234)